# NestJS, Typescript, Unit test fails returning TypeError: Cannot read property 'getById' of undefined

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, nestjs

in my job I'm working with NestJS, but I don't dominate the unit testings. In a module for do CRUD operations with images, there is a unit test but it doesn't works. The code is:

media.gateway.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MediaEntity } from '../entities/media.entity';
import { DBService } from '../../services/db/db.service';
import { NotFoundException } from '../../exceptions/not-found.exception';

@Injectable()
export class MediaGateway {
    private mediaTable: string = 'media';

    constructor(
        private readonly db: DBService,
    ) { }

    public async getById(mediaId: number): Promise<MediaEntity> {
        const mediaRaw: any = await this.db.fetchOne('\
            SELECT id, name, type, private, created, users_id, media_storage_id \
            FROM ' + this.mediaTable + ' \
            WHERE id = ?',
        [ mediaId ]);

        if (!mediaRaw) {
            throw new NotFoundException('Media not found');
        }

        return this.toMediaEntity(mediaRaw);
    }

    private toMediaEntity(media: any): MediaEntity {
        return new MediaEntity(
            media.id,
            media.name,
            media.type ? media.type.toString() : null,
            media.private === 1,
            media.media_storage_id,
            media.users_id,
            new Date(media.created),
        );
    }
}
```

and the unit test is:

media.gateway.spec.ts

```
import { Fixture } from '../../../../test/fixture';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { DBServiceTestProvider } from '../../../../test/db.service.test.provider';
import { MediaEntity, MediaType } from '../entities/media.entity';
import { MediaGateway } from './media.gateway';

describe('Media Gateway', () => {

    let gateway: MediaGateway;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await Fixture.clearAndInit();

        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                MediaGateway,
                DBServiceTestProvider,
            ],
        }).compile();

        gateway = module.get<MediaGateway>(MediaGateway);
    });

    describe('Get existing media by id', async () => {
        it('Should return media entity', async () => {
            const media: MediaEntity = await gateway.getById(1);
            expect(media).toMatchObject(new MediaEntity(
                1,
                'Media Name',
                MediaType.PHOTO,
                false,
                1,
                1,
                new Date('2019-04-25 19:00:05'),
            ));
        });
    });
});
```

But when I try run the test:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getById' of undefined

25 |     describe('Get existing media by id', async () => {
26 |         it('Should return media entity', async () => {
> 27 |             const media: MediaEntity = await gateway.getById(1);
   |                                                      ^
28 |             expect(media).toMatchObject(new MediaEntity(
29 |                 1,
30 |                 'Media Name',
```

I don't understand why, VScode marks doesn't have errors on the code, and the route to media.gateway.ts is fine.

(edited)

If I just:

```
import { Fixture } from '../../../../test/fixture';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { DBServiceTestProvider } from '../../../../test/db.service.test.provider';
import { MediaEntity, MediaType } from '../entities/media.entity';
import { MediaGateway } from './media.gateway2';

describe('Media Gateway', () => {

    let gateway: MediaGateway;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await Fixture.clearAndInit();

        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                MediaGateway,
                DBServiceTestProvider,
            ],
        }).compile();

        gateway = module.get<MediaGateway>(MediaGateway);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(gateway).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Returns:

```
> tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json && jest --no-cache --runInBand "src/core/medias/gateways/media.gateway2.spec.ts"                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 FAIL  src/core/medias/gateways/media.gateway2.spec.ts (6.054s)                                                                                                                                                                    
  Media Gateway                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ✕ should be defined (64ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  ● Media Gateway › should be defined                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    ER_DUP_KEYNAME: Duplicate key name 'value_UNIQUE'

      at Query.Object.<anonymous>.Sequence._packetToError (../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
      at Query.Object.<anonymous>.Query.ErrorPacket (../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
      at Protocol.Object.<anonymous>.Protocol._parsePacket (../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
      at Parser._parsePacket (../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
      at Parser.write (../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
      at Protocol.Object.<anonymous>.Protocol.write (../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (../node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (../node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
          --------------------
      at Protocol.Object.<anonymous>.Protocol._enqueue (../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
      at Connection.query (../node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
      at Promise (../node_modules/postgrator/lib/MysqlClient.js:57:20)
      at MysqlClient._runQuery (../node_modules/postgrator/lib/MysqlClient.js:56:12)
      at MysqlClient.runQuery (../node_modules/postgrator/lib/Client.js:58:19)
      at sequence.then.then.then (../node_modules/postgrator/postgrator.js:217:37)

  ● Media Gateway › should be defined

    expect(received).toBeDefined()

    Received: undefined

      24 |
      25 |     it('should be defined', () => {
    > 26 |         expect(gateway).toBeDefined();
         |                         ^
      27 |     });
      28 |     // describe('Get existing media by id', async () => {
      29 |     //     it('Should return media entity', async () => {

      at Object.it (core/medias/gateways/media.gateway2.spec.ts:26:25)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.078s
```

Comment: this erro appears at runtime, this is why VSC didn't catch it. Arent't you getting any other Nestjs logs in your terminal?

Comment: btw try to follow https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs

Comment: What is the `DBServiceTestProvider`? You probably aren't providing the tokens Nest is expecting to see in the test

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes, finally I inspected the imports, and it seems is a mysql error or something. I discovered that now all the gateways tests fail . The unit test process is fine. Thanks a lot to all guys! :)